# Filter sentencs based on search words using python?

Tags: python, text, nltk

I got a text file containing many sentences. I want to query the text file with search words and return those sentences that contain the query words.

Effort so far:

```
h = input("Enter search word: ")
with open("file.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if  h in part:
                print (part)
```

file.txt contains these sentences

```
On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. 
You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. 
When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.
You can easily change the formatting of selected text in the document text by choosing a look for the selected text from the Quick Styles gallery on the Home tab.
You can also format text directly by using the other controls on the Home tab.
Most controls offer a choice of using the look from the current theme or using a format that you specify directly.
To change the overall look of your document, choose new Theme elements on the Page Layout tab. To change the looks available in the Quick Style gallery, use the Change Current Quick Style Set command.
Both the Themes gallery and the Quick Styles gallery provide reset commands so that you can always restore the look of your document to the original contained in your current template.
```

Output: for the 'galleries' search  it returns galleries twice but i need to return the sentences.

How to query multiple words search and return those sentences containing those combination (not necessarily an n gram or in order) For example if i type 'overall' as one word and 'Layout' as another search word it should return the following sentence. Search words are case insensitive

```
To change the overall look of your document, choose new Theme elements on the Page Layout tab.
```

HELP!

Comment: Use ```nltk```  ```word_tokinizer``` and ```sentence_tokinizer```

Answer (score 1):

This for multiple search words:

```
myfile = "queryfile.txt"
search_wordlist = input("Enter search words, separated by a comma\n")
mylist = search_wordlist.split(",")

with open(myfile) as openfile:
   for line in openfile:
      for term in mylist:
         if term in line:
             print(line)
```

Comment: It works. But can you make the search case insensitive and account for multiple key word search.